# How can I position a web page in the middle of the screen?

Tags: html, css

How can I position a web page in the middle of the screen? like the pages on stackoverflow web site?
I'm writing the masterpage of my website and I want to use HTML and css to position the master page in the middleof the screen and then build the inside positioning  block using css. But I can't get my page to be visualized in the middle!

Thank you!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use margins to position it in the center horizontally.

Given this html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <div id="page"> ... content ... </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The CSS can be as simple as:

```
#page {
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  width:960px;
}
```

You also need to make sure you have a valid doctype for this to work.

Comment: You only need a valid doctype for it to be understood properly by IE.  However, I don't think IE6 understands auto margins.

Comment: I do believe that IE6 understands auto margins if there is a valid doctype present. At least in version 6.0.2900.2180.xpsp_xp2_gdr.080814-1233. Wow that was a mouth full.

Comment: @strager: it can, but you have to use a little css hack where you text-align:center the parent (the body in this case) and then put it back to text-align:left; on the element you want to center.

Comment: @Zack - Auto margins worked for me in two different patched versions of IE6 (afraid I don't have the versions to hand)

Comment: @Coehoorn, That doesn't make auto margins work.  It's a workaround using flaws in IE's understanding of text-align.

Answer (score 6):

Create a `<div>` in your `<body>` like so:

```
<body>
<div id="main">

<!-- ... -->

</div>
</body>
```

And add the following CSS:

```
body {
    text-align: center; /* IE */
}

#main {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: left;   /* IE */
    width: XXX;         /* Fill this out. */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Put all of your content in a container and give it a margin: 0 auto

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="width: 800px; margin: 0px auto;">
  your content here
</div>
```

Check this page if you want horizonal *and* vertical alignment: http://www.wpdfd.com/editorial/thebox/deadcentre2.html

Answer (score 0):

wrap it all in a div with margin: auto and make body have text-align: center.

Answer (score 0):

Let the HTML code be as follows:

```
<body>
  <div class="box">.....</div>
</body>
```

And following be the CSS code:

```
.box{
    width: 200px;
    margin: 10px auto;
}
```

The above CSS code will set the width to 200px for the div and will set from bottom and up to 10px and the margin from left right to `auto` that means it will automatically adjust it's position to center. The `auto` guarantees that the left and right margins will be set to the same size.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple: **display: inline-block**;

```
<div style="text-align: center; display: inline-block; width: specifyYourWidthHere">
    <div>
          //Your TextBox here
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try:

```
<center>
```

---

This is more text to meet the 30character minimum.

Comment: As cheezy as this answer sounds, I have yet to see a browser that it DOESN'T work perfectly fine on..

Comment: i suppose id didn't thoroughly read the question, and i almost put something in my answer saying its not the most elegant, or a css solution.  that being said, it will work.